# Нужна помощь в решении задачи на python!

Tags: python

Дана задача:

> В магазине проходит новогодняя распродажа – цены всех товаров снижены
> на 25%. Оказалось, что первоначально все цены делились на 4, поэтому
> после снижения цен все цены также выражаются целым числом. Товаровед
> вечером перед распродажей снял ценники со всех товаров и напечатал для
> каждого товара ещё один ценник со сниженной ценой. Он оставил все
> ценники на столе, рассчитывая утром их развесить. Но, придя утром в
> магазин, он обнаружил, что уборщица смешала все ценники вместе, и
> теперь ему нужно отделить старые ценники от новых.

Код на python:

```
n = int(input())
prices = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]
count = dict()
for price in prices:
    if price in count:
        count[price] += 1
    else:
        count[price] = 1
for price in prices:
    if count[price] > 0:
        print(price)
        count[price] -= 1
        count[price // 3 * 4] -= 1
```

```
Входные данные: 6 30 40 42 45 56 60
На выходе: 30 42 45
```

Но к сожалению он выдает ошибку "KeyError: 4". Помогите понять, почему?

Comment: Добавили бы трассу стека, чтобы было понятно в каком месте ошибка происходит. И какие входные данные

Comment: Входные данные:
6
30
40
42
45
56
60
На выходе: 
30
42
45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка KeyError возникает, когда  ключ набора (словаря) не найден в наборе существующих ключей.

Ошибка возникает в этой строке
`count[price // 3 * 4] -= 1`

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Проблема решена!!!